# Autocomplete - select option with mouse click - vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, autocomplete, vue-component

Some time ago I created an autocomplete component in vue for a project in which I am involved.

But today I detected a small bug.

When I select the option I want with the click of the mouse, the option does not get transmitted, as you can see in the `console.log ()` that is in the example. If I click on another option again, what will appear in `console.log ()` is the option previously selected.

If I put a `setTimeout( () => {}, 200)` it already detects and emit the option, but I think it is not the best solution for this case.

Any suggestion?

**example**

```js
const Autocomplete = {
  name: "autocomplete",
  template: "#autocomplete",
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      required: false,
      default: () => Array(150).fill().map((_, i) => `Fruit ${i+1}`)
    },
    isAsync: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
      default: false
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      isOpen: false,
      results: [],
      search: "",
      isLoading: false,
      arrowCounter: 0
    };
  },

  methods: {
    onChange() {
      console.log( this.search)
      // Let's warn the parent that a change was made
      this.$emit("input", this.search);
    },
    setResult(result, i) {
      this.arrowCounter = i;
      this.search = result;
      this.isOpen = false;
    },
    showAll() {
      this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
   (this.isOpen) ? this.results = this.items : this.results = [];
    },
  },
  computed: {
      filterResults() {
      // first uncapitalize all the things
      this.results = this.items.filter(item => {
        return item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1;
      });
      
     
      return this.results;
    },
  },
  watch: {
    items: function(val, oldValue) {
      // actually compare them
      if (val.length !== oldValue.length) {
        this.results = val;
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    document.addEventListener("click", this.handleClickOutside);
  },
  destroyed() {
    document.removeEventListener("click", this.handleClickOutside);
  }
};

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  name: "app",
  components: {
    autocomplete: Autocomplete
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
  width: 130px;
}

.autocomplete-results {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.autocomplete-result {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.autocomplete-result.is-active,
.autocomplete-result:hover {
  background-color: #4aae9b;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <autocomplete />

</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="autocomplete">
  <div class="autocomplete">
    <input type="text" @blur="onChange" v-model="search"  @click="showAll" />
    <ul id="autocomplete-results" v-show="isOpen" ref="scrollContainer" class="autocomplete-results">
      <li class="loading" v-if="isLoading">
        Loading results...
      </li>
      <li ref="options" v-else v-for="(result, i) in filterResults" :key="i" @click="setResult(result, i)" class="autocomplete-result" :class="{ 'is-active': i === arrowCounter }">
        {{ result }}
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using onblur event, but its fired when you click outside and before the onclick's item listener, so the value wasn't updated.

Use onchange event to capture data if user types anything in the input and call onChange() method inside setResult().

```js
const Autocomplete = {
  name: "autocomplete",
  template: "#autocomplete",
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      required: false,
      default: () => Array(150).fill().map((_, i) => `Fruit ${i+1}`)
    },
    isAsync: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
      default: false
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      isOpen: false,
      results: [],
      search: "",
      isLoading: false,
      arrowCounter: 0
    };
  },

  methods: {
    onChange() {
      console.log( this.search)
      // Let's warn the parent that a change was made
      this.$emit("input", this.search);
    },
    setResult(result, i) {
      this.arrowCounter = i;
      this.search = result;
      this.isOpen = false;
      // Fire onChange, because it won't do it on blur
      this.onChange();
    },
    showAll() {
      this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
   (this.isOpen) ? this.results = this.items : this.results = [];
    },
  },
  computed: {
      filterResults() {
      // first uncapitalize all the things
      this.results = this.items.filter(item => {
        return item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1;
      });
      
     
      return this.results;
    },
  },
  watch: {
    items: function(val, oldValue) {
      // actually compare them
      if (val.length !== oldValue.length) {
        this.results = val;
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    document.addEventListener("click", this.handleClickOutside);
  },
  destroyed() {
    document.removeEventListener("click", this.handleClickOutside);
  }
};

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  name: "app",
  components: {
    autocomplete: Autocomplete
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
  width: 130px;
}

.autocomplete-results {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.autocomplete-result {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.autocomplete-result.is-active,
.autocomplete-result:hover {
  background-color: #4aae9b;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <autocomplete />

</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="autocomplete">
  <div class="autocomplete">
    <input type="text" @change="onChange" v-model="search"  @click="showAll" />
    <ul id="autocomplete-results" v-show="isOpen" ref="scrollContainer" class="autocomplete-results">
      <li class="loading" v-if="isLoading">
        Loading results...
      </li>
      <li ref="options" v-else v-for="(result, i) in filterResults" :key="i" @click="setResult(result, i)" class="autocomplete-result" :class="{ 'is-active': i === arrowCounter }">
        {{ result }}
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: I detected when I write part of the option, and then select the option with the click mouse, the `onChange` function is called twice, is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

`blur` is the wrong event to use here, and I think you're over complicating it. Simply call your `emit` in `setResult`:

```js
setResult(result, i) {
      this.arrowCounter = i;
      this.search = result;
      this.isOpen = false;     
      this.$emit("input", this.search);
    },
```